# What hadith mentions the ten companions (al-'Ashara al-Mubashara) in Jannah?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, history, reference-request

I have read somewhere that Prophet (SAW) himself told the good news to ten (10) of his companions that they will have a place in Jannah. These ten companions are called al-'Ashara al-Mubashara (العشرة المبشرة)

Can anybody point me to a historical reference like a Sahih hadith where this is mentioned and who were these ten (10) companions exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The narration pertaining to these ten companions is recorded by Ahmad (1/193) and At-Tirmithee (no. 3747). ‘Abdur-Rahmaan Ibn ‘Awf (radiallahu anhu) narrated that the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) said:

> أَبُو بَكْرٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعُمَرُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعَلِيٌّ فِي
>   الْجَنَّةِ وَعُثْمَانُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَطَلْحَةُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ
>   وَالزُّبَيْرُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ عَوْفٍ فِي
>   الْجَنَّةِ وَسَعْدُ بْنُ أَبِي وَقَّاصٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَسَعِيدُ بْنُ
>   زَيْدِ بْنِ عَمْرِو بْنِ نُفَيْلٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَأَبُو عُبَيْدَةَ
>   بْنُ الْجَرَّاحِ فِي الْجَنَّةِ
>
> Abu Bakr is in Paradise, ‘Umar is in Paradise, ‘Alee is in Paradise,
>   ‘Uthmaan is in Paradise, Talhah is in Paradise, Az-Zubayr is in
>   Paradise, ‘Abdur-Rahmaan Ibn ‘Awf is in Paradise, Sa’d Ibn Abee
>   Waqqaas is in Paradise, Sa’eed Ibn Zayd Ibn ‘Amr Ibn Nufayl is in
>   Paradise, and Abu ‘Ubaydah Ibn Al-Jarraah is in Paradise.

It also has other supporting narrations by way of Sa’d Ibn Zaid (radiallahu anhu) from Ahmad (1/187-188) and At-Tirmithee (no. 3747).