# Shia view about three righteous caliphs (Other than Ali R.A.)

Tags: hadith, shiism, caliph

There is a Sahih Hadith stating the names of ten (10) people who the Prophet (SA) stated that they will be in Paradise. These names include the names of four righteous caliphs, Abu Bakar RA, Umer RA, Uthman RA and Ali RA among others. Please see [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/hadith-about-ashra-mubashara?rq=1) for details about the Hadith I am talking about...

Now, from the questions on this website, I have got the impression that Shias believe that Abu Bakar RA and Umer RA did many wrong things against Ahl ul Bayt.

So, my question is:

1. Do Shia believe that these three righteous caliphs will end up in Paradise?
2. Do they believe that this Hadith is not correct? If they do believe this, what are the reasons behind this belief?
3. Do they believe that Prophet (S.A.)'s judgement was wrong?

Or is there a 4th dimension to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) that hadith is not authentic and is fabricated. ([explain](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/hadith-about-ashra-mubashara/5334#5334)).

> 1-Do Shia believe that these three righteous caliphs will end up in Paradise?

No, Shia Muslims does not have such a belief.

> Do they believe that this Hadith is not correct?

Yes, Shia Muslims believe that this hadith is not authentic and is fabricated.

> If they do believe this, what are the reasons behind this belief?

This hadith contains contradictions :

Imam Ali a.s. considered Killing Talha and Zubair permitted when they didn't returned and Talha and Zubair also considered killing Imam Ali a.s. permitted and they fought each other at  the Camel war with Talha and Zubair being killed in this war. They were enemy of each other. **How it is possible that two enemy can both go to paradise while fighting and killing each other?**
Quran says:

> وَمَن يَقْتُلْ مُؤْمِنًا مُّتَعَمِّدًا فَجَزَاؤُهُ جَهَنَّمُ خَالِدًا
> فِيهَا وَغَضِبَ اللَّـهُ عَلَيْهِ وَلَعَنَهُ وَأَعَدَّ لَهُ عَذَابًا
> عَظِيمًا
>
> But whoever fights [or murders] a believer intentionally - his recompense is Hell,
> wherein he will abide eternally, and Allah has become angry with him
> and has cursed him and has prepared for him a great punishment.
> http://tanzil.net/#4:93

Talha and Zubair were in the army of Aisha fighting Imam Ali (a.s.) and both were killed in this , then how both side can go to paradise?

Another proof:

Imam Ali a.s. had serious conflicts with Abubakr,Umar and Uthman and each of them had conflicts with each other. Imam Ali a.s. did not accept to follow methods of Abubakr, Umar and Uthman ([scanned Sunni ref](http://www.sonnat.net/upload/article/E1591B7D.25CB.4931/H18OSJSL_pic.png?rnd=)). Imam Ali a.s. did not participate in the attack of Umar to Iran because had conflict with Umar about the legitimacy of this attack and disagreed this action.

There are many other conflicts between Imam Ali a.s. and Abubakr,Umar and Uthman. Here is a famous sermon from Imam Ali a.s. about them recorded in many Shia and Sunni books:

[Sermon 3 Sermon of ash-Shiqshiqiyyah](http://www.al-islam.org/nahj/) (Including Sunni references)

Also Abdu Alrahman Ibn Auf had serious contradictions with Uthman and was at wrathful with Uthamn until his death.

**How so many inconsistency is possible if this hadith is authentic?!**

> In the camel war before the war starts Imam Ali a.s. called Talha and
> Zubair and said them: do you know that the companions of Camel are
> cursed?
>
> Zubair replied: how we are cursed while we are promised to paradise?
>
> Imam Ali a.s.: if I considered you from people of paradise I did not
> fight you and did not consider your blood Halal.
>
> Zubair said: have not you heared the hadith of Saiid Ibn Amru Ibn
> Nafil from prophet that ten people from Quraish are in paradise?
>
> Imam Ali a.s. said: I heard he said this hadith at time of Caliphet of
> Uthman for him.
>
> Zubair said: did he lie?
>
> Imam Ali a.s. said: I do not say anything until you tell their names.
>
> Zubair said the name of nine of them.
>
> Imam Ali a.s. said: who is the 10th?
>
> Zubair said: it is you.
>
> Imam Ali a.s. said: so you admitted that I am from companions of
> paradise. but I deny what you claim about yourself and your companions.
>
> Zubair said: do you doubt that Saiid lied?
>
> Imam Ali a.s. said: I do not doubt. I am sure he lied and some of
> them are in coffin in the lowest Darak of Hell and at top of that well
> is a stone that when Allah wants to punish the people of Hell
> removes that stone. I heard this from prophet.
>
> Zubair cried and returned.  ([ref](http://makarem.ir/websites/farsi/squestions/?gro=289))

**Do they believe that Prophet (SA)'s judgement was wrong?**

No, Shia believe prophet was infallible and did not committed any mistake nor any sin nor any Makruh.

---

**References and more study:**

[The Opinion of Imam Ali (AS) on Caliphate](http://www.al-islam.org/encyclopedia/chapter3/9.html)

[Caliphate and Imamate](http://www.al-islam.org/caliphate-imamate-ahmad-namaee/)

[Imam Ali (a.s.) and the Caliphate](http://english.bayynat.org/infallibles/ali.htm)

[Imamate The Vicegerency of the Prophet [s]](http://www.al-islam.org/imamate-vicegerency-prophet-sayyid-saeed-akhtar-rizvi)

[About the hadith ten Mubashere hadith](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/questionview.html?questionid=12342)

[Contradiction inside the hadith of ten Mubashare hadith](http://sonnat.net/article.asp?id=428&cat=88)