# Inner sects of Shias and beliefs regarding wives of Nabi SAW and companions

Tags: shiism

I have heard (only heard and not saying its true) that Shia curse some of the wives of Nabi SAW like Aisha RA as well some or all of the first 3 caliphs of Islam. My question is: is this true and if yes, is it done by a majority or minority of Shia?

Comment: Can you limit your questions to **1 question** as it is too broad and therefore will be closed as being too broad?

Comment: ok done, limited to 1

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/shia-view-about-three-righteous-caliphs-other-than-ali-r-a

Comment: ask your question clearly please.

Answer (score 2):

```
                                    بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

Briefly speaking, in regards to Prophet Muhammad's wife/wives and exclusively Aishah, I/we as Shia Muslim(s) who follow the attitude/manner of Ahlul-Bait, we know that e.g. albeit Aishah was as an enemy of/against Imam Ali (a.s.) in Jamal war --and we really criticize her owing to this and ...-- but despite it, Imam Ali didn't disrespect her, beside, Shia Islam doesn't disrespect her since she is regarded as a wife of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his family), hence due to the respect of the Prophet (SAWW) we don't disrespect her anyhow.

Meanwhile, if I'm not mistaken, all or majority of Shia scholars don't allow to curse/insult her (despite having serious criticism about her). Eventually, on the whole, based on my vast observation/assumption I conclude that most Shia Muslims don't disrespect/curse her.

**For instance, Ayatollah Khamenei as the supreme leader of Iran and likewise as a famous Marja'al-taqlid of Shia (that he + Ayatollah Sistani can be regarded as the 2 first Marja'al-Taqlid of Shia from the aspect of fame and Moqaleds (followers)) declared that: it is haram to insult Ayashah and symbols of Sunnis.**

---

**Reference** :

- [www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View](http://%20http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/64105/%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%B9%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%D9%87)
- [www.asriran.com/fa](http://www.asriran.com/fa/news/138651/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B9%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%D9%87-%D9%88-%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA)

Comment: i know that Imam Khomeini issued some fatwa regarding this, is this possible to support your answer using fatwas issued by important people within Shia Islam, thanks

Comment: Your welcome. Hopefully I will add to it now in short